# jquery multiselect dropdown value format

Tags: jquery, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have custom columns in jqgrid . One is multiselect dropdown , I have tried with key value pair its not working . then i had tried this hardcoded data is working but if i give json format it'll not work .

```
    var columnDisplay = [
    {name:"platform", label:"Platform", width:"400",editrules: true, edittype:"select",Overflow: "visible",
                             editoptions: { 
                                 value: data,
                                 dataInit: function (elem) {
                                     $(elem).multiselect({
                                         includeSelectAllOption: true,
                                         enableFiltering: true,
                                         maxWidth: 400, //'auto',
                                         maxHeight: 135,
                                         multiselect:true,
                                         selectedList: 3,
                                         noneSelectedText: "Please select",
                                         open: function () {
                                             var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible");
                                             $menu.width("auto");
                                             return;
                                         }
                                     });

                                 },
                                 multiple: true, 
                             },
                             editable : true,
                         },
]
```

If i give **data** as **data = {1:"val1",2:"val2",3:"val3"}** it works .

But,

object that i have modified same as above ,

object contains (obj is) **"{"1":"val1","2":"val2","3":"val3"}"**

```
var data = JSON.stringify(obj);
    data =data.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:').replace(/\'/g, '"');
```

but this is not working !! Please help

**found it in other way**

```
var columnDisplay = [
    {name:"platform", label:"Platform", width:"400",editrules: true, edittype:"select",Overflow: "visible",
                             editoptions: { 

                                        dataInit: function (elem) {
                                     $(elem).multiselect({
                                         includeSelectAllOption: true,
                                         enableFiltering: true,
                                         maxWidth: 400, //'auto',
                                         maxHeight: 135,
                                         multiselect:true,
                                         selectedList: 3,
                                         noneSelectedText: "Please select",
                                         open: function () {
                                             var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible");
                                             $menu.width("auto");
                                             return;
                                         }
                                     });

                           **$(elem).multiselect('dataprovider',data);** // data is in key value pair format
                                 },
                                 multiple: true, 
                             },
                             editable : true,
                         },
]
```

Comment: It seems your data is a string since with object like `value: {"1":"val1","2":"val2","3":"val3"}` it is working. In case of string you just need to parese the string to json woth JSON.parse - i.e `value : JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: @TonyTomov tried which u suggested .. its showing empty in the dropdown :(